# Updating audio buffering bars

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I have a simple audio player. I'm trying to make the buffering progress bar work as expected but I'm unable to do it. There are no errors but the behavior is very different, I'll show you:

[image: Image 01]

In this image, the green bar is the loaded part, and the light-grey is the media buffering.

Now, I'll jump to the end of the video +-

[image: Image 02]

Until now, everything is perfect, but if I rewind to the beginning, for example, the light grey buffering bar do not reset =>

[image: Image 03]

After searching for all forums and pages, I didnt find any solution for this, seems that media buffering do not allow you to do a lot, I dont know if I'm 100% sure. Here is my code =>

```js
window.onload = function(){ 

    var myAudio = document.getElementById('my-audio');

    myAudio.addEventListener('progress', function() {
      var bufferedEnd = myAudio.buffered.end(myAudio.buffered.length - 1);
      var duration =  myAudio.duration;
      if (duration > 0) {
        document.getElementById('buffered-amount').style.width = ((bufferedEnd / duration)*100) + "%";
      }
    });

    myAudio.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
      var duration =  myAudio.duration;
      if (duration > 0) {
        document.getElementById('progress-amount').style.width = ((myAudio.currentTime / duration)*100) + "%";
      }
    });
  }
```

```css
  .buffered { 
    height: 20px; 
    position: relative;
    background: #555;
    width: 300px;
  }

  #buffered-amount {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #777;
    width: 0;
  }

  .progress { 
    margin-top: -20px;
    height: 20px;  
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
  }

  #progress-amount {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #595;
    width: 0;
  }
```

```html
<audio id="my-audio" preload controls>
  <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
<div class="buffered">
  <span id="buffered-amount"></span>
</div>
<div class="progress">
  <span id="progress-amount"></span>
</div>
```

How can I fix it? As far I know, the buffering progress bar must return to the seeked part and start buffering again, like the first image I posted. Not leaving this huge grey bar trail, as in the last image I put.

Thank you.

Comment: `the buffering progress bar must return to the seeked part` WHY? If you rewind, why would you lose the audio you already loaded? seems like your images shows exactly what I would expect

Comment: Note that if I seek from minute 1 to minute 10, for example, there will be no loaded data from minute 4 to 7, for example. It will just leave a random huge grey trail bar

Comment: oh, yeah ... that's a point - that'll be hard to show all the gaps then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create one "buffered-amount" element per item in `myAudio.buffered`. You then can set their `left` value to the result of `buffered.start(index)`, and their `width` to the end value minus the start value:

```js
window.onload = function(){ 

    var myAudio = document.getElementById('my-audio');

    myAudio.addEventListener('progress', function() {
      // remove all previous elems
      document.querySelectorAll('.buffered .buffered-amount')
        .forEach((el) => el.remove());
      const { buffered, duration } = myAudio;
      if (duration > 0) {
        for (let index = 0; index < buffered.length; index++) {
          const start = buffered.start(index);
          const end   = buffered.end(index);
          const elem = document.createElement("span");
          elem.classList.add("buffered-amount");
          elem.style.left = ((start / duration)*100) + "%";
          elem.style.width = (((end - start) / duration)*100) + "%";
          document.querySelector('.buffered').append(elem);
        }
      }
    });

    myAudio.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
      var duration =  myAudio.duration;
      if (duration > 0) {
        document.getElementById('progress-amount').style.width = ((myAudio.currentTime / duration)*100) + "%";
      }
    });
  }
```

```css
.buffered { 
    height: 20px; 
    position: relative;
    background: #555;
    width: 300px;
  }

.buffered-amount {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #777;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

.progress { 
  margin-top: -20px;
  height: 20px;  
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
}

#progress-amount {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #595;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<audio id="my-audio" preload controls>
  <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
<div class="buffered">
  
</div>
<div class="progress">
  <span id="progress-amount"></span>
</div>
```